# Wp_mail not working with css classes

Tags: php, css, email

I use `wp_mail` html content type to send emails.

```
ob_start();  
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
  <p class="main">This is main content!!</p>
</html>
<?php
$message = ob_get_contents();
$message = "<p class=\"main\">this is main content</p>"
$subject = "test_email";
$headers = "From: admin <info@example.com>";
wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

and the `style.css` is here:

```
.main{
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 25px;
}
```

But this code doesn't render HTML/CSS classes. How can i fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: put the styles in a style tag `<style>.main{
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 25px;
}</style>` in the header instaed of a relative link

Comment: Thank you. But that does not actually work... @Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify style inline, because when letter is received there is no main class.

Try:

```
$message = "<p style=\"font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 25px;\">this is main content</p>";
```

Comment: Thank you. Consider this situation: i wanna set my installed font-family (by font-face property in css) to wp_mail. Can i do that?

Comment: @sajastu Yes, you can do this by adding <style>your css code</style> at the beginning of your html letter, but all links should use absolute paths (actually i don't know if links are allowed)

Comment: I try <style> tag. But it doesn't render at email side. it seems only inline-style work here ...

Answer (score 0):

Write the styles inline, almost all email clients ignore css stylesheets or re-strucutre the code to its own style.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately i found the correct way to do my work.
when you use `wp_mail()` you can just use `inline-css`. All the css properties can be implemented at email side. However you can not use stylesheet (or sytle tag).
i almost googled entire web for last 2 days, But i don't find another solution except inlie CSS (which i used). Hope to see some other ways in future.